# R - Incorrect calculations for small values

Tags: r, underflow

I consider the following function: -x*exp(-x) - (1+exp(-x))*log(1+exp(-x))

It is a continuous function, but while plotting it in R I get a weird discontinuous graph over x from -38 to -34 (which is not really so low as to reach Inf/-Inf in the calculations). For example, the output for x=-37.36 and x=-37.38 is 0, but for x=-37.37 is -128. What could be the reason for this?

I am probably making some very basic error, but any help would be great. I have added the code and the plot.

Thanks!

```
x=seq(from=-38,to=-34,by=0.01)
kappa = -x*exp(-x) - (1+exp(-x))*log(1+exp(-x))

plot(x,kappa)
```

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNziB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula suffers from a phenomenon due to the precision of floating point numbers.
When you add small values to large numbers there is always the risk of precision loss.

```r
x <- seq(from=-38, to=-0, by=1)
v1 <- exp(-x)
v2 <- 1 + v1
# The difference between `v1` and `v2` should be 1, however:
v1 - v2
#>  [1]  0  0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
#> [26] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

One simple solution would be using a package that provides floating point with higher precision like the `Rmpfr` package (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49263592/13241545)). Another would be to find an alternate form that avoids `+1` and `exp(-x) + exp(x)`.

It is important to note, that this is not flaw in `R` but a [general issue of floating point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance).

<sup>Created on 2021-03-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>