# R nleqslv difficulties - solving for pH in an acid-base buffer

Tags: r, numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization, chemistry, nonlinear-equation

## Goal

Build a theoretical titration curve for the phosphoric acid buffer (1M).

I provide a fully reproducible and self-contained example (of my failures ^.^).

## Model equations

Acid-base equilibrium equations for phosphoric acid are:

[image: phospho_equilibrium]

## Model implementation

```r
Ka.1 <- 7.1 * 10^-3 
Ka.2 <- 6.3 * 10^-8
Ka.3 <- 4.5 * 10^-13
Kw <- 10^-14

balance <- function(vars, Na_ca, P_ca, convert.fun=function(x) x){
  # Apply positive only constraint
  vars <- convert.fun(vars)
  
  H <- vars[1]
  H3A <- vars[2]
  H2A <- vars[3]
  HA <- vars[4]
  A <- vars[5]
  Na <- convert.fun(Na_ca)

  eq.system <- c(H3A + H2A + HA + A - P_ca, 
                 H + Na - Kw/H - H2A - 2*HA - 3*A, 
                 H * H2A / Ka.1 - H3A,
                 H * HA  / Ka.2 - H2A, 
                 H * A   / Ka.3 - HA
                 )
  return(eq.system)
}
```

Notice that `convert.fun` is there to try different ways of forcing positive values on concentrations.

The return value is a vector of the model's equations, equated to zero (is this right?).

### Iteration

I wished to solve the system for all possible Na+ concentrations, up to 3 equivalence "volumes".

I set initial conditions that woked for the lowest one: `[Na]=0`.

Then solved it with `nleqslv` and used the result to "seed" the next iteration.

And it seemed to work nicely:

[image: titration curve]

But, on close inspection, the issues will become obvious.

> But, before that, some code!

Setup initial conditions and results matrix:

```r
P_ca <- 1
ci.start <- c(H=10^-1, H3A=0.9, H2A=0.1, HA=0.1, A=0.1)
Na.seq <- seq(from=0,to=3*P_ca,by=P_ca/1000)

varnames <- c("Na", "H",  "H3A", "H2A", "HA",  "A")

result.m <- matrix(ncol = length(varnames), nrow = length(Na.seq))
colnames(result.m) <- varnames

result.m[,1] <- Na.seq
```

Iteration:

```r
convert.fun <- function(x) abs(x)

for(i in 1:length(Na.seq)){
  
  Na_ca <- result.m[i,1]
  
  if(i == 1){                   # Si es la primera iteración,
    ci <- ci.start              # usar los valores "start" como C.I.
  } else {                      # Si no,
    ci <- result.m[i-1, 2:6]    # usar los valores de la solución anterior
  }
  
  result <- nleqslv::nleqslv(x = ci, 
                             fn = balance, 
                             Na = Na_ca, P = P_ca,
                             convert.fun = convert.fun,
                             method="Newton",  #method="Broyden",
                             global="dbldog",
                             control = list(allowSingular=TRUE,
                                            maxit=1000))
  
  result$x <- convert.fun(result$x)
  
  result.m[i,2:6] <- result$x
  
  stopifnot(all(result$x >= 0))
  
} # END LOOP

result.df <- as.data.frame(result.m)
```

Notice that `convert.fun` is now `abs(x)` (is this ok?).

## The problem

The problem with the last plot is that the right part of it is flattened out.

The problem is even more obvious in the following plot:

[image]

The red curve is supossed to end up at the top, and the purple one at the bottom. This seems to start happening at `Na~2`, but after a few more iterations, the result flattens out (and becomes exactly constant).

## Possible hints for the savvy

- The problem is a bit worse using `method="Broyden"` instead of `"Newton"`.
- `nleqslv`'s return message changes from "Function criterion near zero" to "x-values within tolerance 'xtol'".
- I also tried adding a Jacobian. That didnt change the result, but at the problematic point I get something like this:

```
    Chkjac  possible error in jacobian[2,1] =  2.7598836276240e+06
                             Estimated[2,1] =  1.1104869955110e+04
```

I am now really out of ideas! And would really appreciate some help or guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always test the termination code of `nleqslv` to determine if a solution has been found. And somehow display the termination code and/or the message `nleqslv` returns. You will see that in some case no better point was found. Therefore any result is invalid and useless.

You are using so many values for `Na.seq` that it is impossible to the wood through the trees.

I would suggest starting with a very limited set of values for `Na.seq`.
Something like

```
Na.seq <- seq(from=0,to=3*P_ca,by=P_ca/10)
```

and also this to include the termination code in the result

```
varnames <- c("Na", "H",  "H3A", "H2A", "HA",  "A", "termcd")

result.m <- matrix(ncol = length(varnames), nrow = length(Na.seq))
```

And then change the iteration loop to this

```
for(i in 1:length(Na.seq)){

  Na_ca <- result.m[i,1]

  if(i == 1){                   # Si es la primera iteración,
    ci <- ci.start              # usar los valores "start" como C.I.
  } else {                      # Si no,
    ci <- result.m[i-1, 2:6]    # usar los valores de la solución anterior
  }

  iter.trace <- 1
  cat("Iteration ",i,"\n\n")
  result <- nleqslv::nleqslv(x = ci, 
                             fn = balance, 
                             Na = Na_ca, P = P_ca,
                             convert.fun = convert.fun,
                             method="Newton",  #method="Broyden",
                             global="dbldog",
                             control = list(allowSingular=TRUE,
                                            maxit=1000,trace=iter.trace))
  cat("\n\n ",result$message,"\n\n") 
  result$x <- convert.fun(result$x)

  result.m[i,2:6] <- result$x
  result.m[i,7] <- result$termcd

  stopifnot(all(result$x >= 0))

} # END LOOP
```

and start analysing the output to find out what the problem is and where.

**Addendum**

I am reasonably sure that the difficulties with solving are (partly) caused by numerical difficulties. With the above modifications I changed the values for `Ka.1`, `Ka.2`, `Ka.3`,and `Kw` to

```
Ka.1 <- 7.1 * 10^-1
Ka.2 <- 6.3 * 10^-3
Ka.3 <- 4.5 * 10^-3
Kw <- 10^-3
```

and then there are no problems in finding a solution (all termination codes are 1). I suspect that the very small values for the `K...` constants are the cause of the problem. Check the system for possible errors or try to change the measurement units of the variables.

Comment: Thank you Bhas! I have tried your variants (and included changing scalex, see plots here: https://imgur.com/a/pkMmggr ). Next, I'll follow your suggestion and try to transform the system somehow, to avoid small/large numbers. Do you happen to know what scalex really did?

Comment: `nleqslv` works with scaled variables. A user function works with unscaled variables. The scale factors are the inverse of the size of the variables. Default is `1`.

Comment: Thanks! Yep i read the documentation, i was struggling to understand what effect it might have on numerical problems. I lowered the Ka's as suggested, but [the problem persists](https://imgur.com/a/dgyJCCD) (but it is no longer constant!). As you said, numerical problems really seem to be the cause, because by just reordering [one expression](https://imgur.com/a/o5uUyUE) i get something better (i was inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49265217/11524079)).

Comment: [It finally works](https://imgur.com/a/UIyHDL0)! Thank you! ¿Should i accept your answer and make second one for the details? The key changes was setting `scalex=1/ci`  specifying the Jacobian, and tuning `xtol=1e-10` and `maxit=1000`.

Comment: You have already accepted my answer and provided details.

Comment: I will have a good look at your repo. Congratulations.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution details

Find details and full code [at this repo](https://github.com/naikymen/titration).

The numerical method worked, and the analytical answer provided [at chemistry stackexchange](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/149285/107836) happily coincides :)

[image]

Sadly it does not match experimental data from Julia Martín *et al* (DOI 10.20431/2349-0403.0409002). Perhaps I'll post a question about it on chemistry stackexchange.

My thanks to everyone who helped out <3

Lastly, important plots from the numerical simulation:

[image]